# Symfony 5.0.8 loading infinitely after running the server

Tags: symfony, infinite-loop

I installed Symfony 5.0.8, but it doesn't have server bundle, then installed server bundle v4.4.8, and after putting the server to run from the command line, the URL was generated successfully. I copied the URL to the browser to lunch the home page, but it's loading infinitely.

Comment: Are you on dev environment ? , what's append on console when you run on browser ? Have you try clear cache ?

Comment: The web server bundles has been replaced by the [Symfony CLI](https://symfony.com/download) executable for 5.x and beyond.  As you discovered, it is possible to install the 4.x server bundle but it then requires assorted tweaking depending on your specific setup.  Get the executable and use it to create new projects and to act as a development server going forward.  Or be prepared to roll up your sleeves and dive deep into the internals.

Comment: Yes, I am on Dev environment. Nothing appends to the console when I run on the browser.  have cleared the cache but the error still exists.

Comment: I have also installed Symfony CLI but couldn't find it on my system in order to used it. Please don't laugh at me,  am new to Symfony

Comment: It is not a Symfony issue but rather an operating system issue.  You need to place the symfony executable someplace where the system can find it.  Depends on your OS.

Comment: Am using windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on console, go to your symfony project folder and run

> symfony server:start

You should have something like this on console :

> [OK] Web server listening
>   The Web server is using PHP CGI 7.4.2
>   https://127.0.0.1:8000

You must don't close console, and after this when you run this url on browser, all server do is write on console.